# Error installing Rails 6.0.2.2 with Ruby 2.7.0.0 - The last version of nokogiri (>= 1.6) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.10.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am on Windows and running Ruby 2.7.0.

When running `gem install rails` I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails: 
        The last version of nokogiri (>= 1.6) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.10.9. 
        Try installing it with `gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.9` and then running the current command again
        nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.3, < 2.7.dev. The current ruby version is 2.7.0.0.
```

When I run `gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.9'` I get the same exact error.

I have installed `gem install nokogiri -v 1.11.0.rc1 --pre` , but I'm still getting the same errors.

```
$ nokogiri -v 
# Nokogiri (1.11.0.rc1) 
    ---
    warnings: []
    nokogiri: 1.11.0.rc1
    ruby:
      version: 2.7.0
      platform: x64-mingw32
      description: ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x64-mingw32]       
      engine: ruby
    libxml:
      source: packaged
      patches:
      - 0001-Revert-Do-not-URI-escape-in-server-side-includes.patch
      - 0002-Remove-script-macro-support.patch
      - 0003-Update-entities-to-remove-handling-of-ssi.patch
      - 0004-libxml2.la-is-in-top_builddir.patch
      compiled: 2.9.10
      loaded: 2.9.10
    libxslt:
      source: packaged
      patches: []
      compiled: 1.1.34
      loaded: 1.1.34
```

So, I understand that Ruby 2.7.0 is later than 2.7.dev, but I have the nokogiri gem installed.

Also, everything was working fine with Ruby 2.6.5. I did uninstall it, remove it from the Path, and restart my machine.

If anybody has any ideas I would love to hear them.

Comment: Please run `gem env` and `gem list nokogiri` and paste the output into your question, formatted appropriately, without using "edit" or "update" type tags.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you are trying to install `nokogiri` it installs a version which is not compatible with your ruby version and shows that error.

Even when you specify the version to install, it'll ignore the version number specified and install the latest one as shown in your error.

```
$ nokogiri -v 
# Nokogiri (1.11.0.rc1) 
    ---
    warnings: []
    nokogiri: 1.11.0.rc1
```

So try to make the gem makes the download itself for the currently installed ruby version.

```sh
gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby
```

PS This could take a while...